# Cannot read property 'Available' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to parse a JSON object from an API using React, but I can't figure out how to get the value of child objects. Getting values from the root of the JSON is working fine. What am I missing?

JSON:

```
{
  "AllocDirStats": {
    "Available": 511630798848,
    "Device": "",
    "InodesUsedPercent": 0,
    "Mountpoint": "",
    "Size": 536868810752,
    "Used": 25238011904,
    "UsedPercent": 4.700964443929746
  },
  "CPU": [
    {
      "CPU": "",
      "Idle": 100,
      "System": 0,
      "Total": 0,
      "User": 0
    }
  ],
  "CPUTicksConsumed": 0,
  "DiskStats": [
    {
      "Available": 511630798848,
      "Device": "C:",
      "InodesUsedPercent": 0,
      "Mountpoint": "C:",
      "Size": 536868810752,
      "Used": 25238011904,
      "UsedPercent": 4.700964443929746
    }
  ],
  "Memory": {
    "Available": 30044225536,
    "Free": 0,
    "Total": 34359328768,
    "Used": 4315103232
  },
  "Timestamp": 1494912754632734000,
  "Uptime": 1747472
}
```

JSX:

```
var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            client: []
        }
    },

    componentDidMount: function() {
        const makeRequest = () => axios.get("http://@Model.IP:4646/v1/client/stats").then(({ data }) => this.setState({ client: data }));
        this.serverRequest = makeRequest();
        this.poll = setInterval(() => {
            this.serverRequest = makeRequest();
        }, 60000) // Poll every 60 seconds
    },

    componentWillUnmount: function() {
        this.serverRequest.abort();
        clearInterval(this.poll)
    },

    render: function() {
        const { client } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                {client.Memory.Available}
            </div>
        )
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Results in `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Available' of undefined`

However, if I change `{clinet.Memory.Available}` to `{client.Uptime}` for example, it works, and I get `1747472`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that your `render` function runs the code even before your API call succeeded. So, the code will try to access empty `client` state, which is by default `[]`. The program could not find `Available` there, since `Memory` is `undefined` of `[]`.

My suggestion is to check the state first in the render function. Because JS is type juggling, you can change it like this:

```js
var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            client: null
        }
    },

    // the rest of the code is same

    render: function() {
        const { client } = this.state;
        
        if(client === null) {
            return (<div></div>); // or return null
        }
        
        return (
            <div>
                {client.Memory.Available}
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you :)